# Phase 10 skip card 2 player

Tags: phase-10

When playing phase 10 with 2 players.  Player one goes out and discards the skip, does player two get to play the run in their hands for the phase they’re on or do they have to take the points for not laying down their hand their last turn before they were skipped?

Comment: The question isn’t clear… why would player 2 have the needed run in their hand; why wouldn’t they have played it when they drew it?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a few things mixed up about the rules. The answer to the question is “no”, but it has nothing to do with the skip card. The round ends when a player goes out, either by discarding their last card or by hitting on an existing phase to get rid of their last card. When player 1 went out, the round was over, and player 2 does not get a turn. It is irrelevant if the last card discarded was a Skip card or not.

In addition to that, player 2 should not have been holding cards they could have played. If they had what they needed for their phase in their hand, then they would have played it on their previous turn. If they don’t have the required cards for their phase, then they wouldn’t be allowed to lay down any cards even if they did get another turn. You have to complete your phase before you can lay down any other cards.

Comment: _In addition to that, player 2 should not have been holding cards they could have played._ -  While this is generally good advice, it isn't always true. It sometimes makes sense to keep a phase in hand until you can get rid of all cards in one go.

Comment: @Aaganrmu Can you explain? I know such a thing is true in other sort-of similar games like Canasta, but what reason would there ever be for not completing a phase as soon as you can? It's a big risk and is there any potential reward?

Comment: If I am am only missing a 2 and 9 to complete a 10-card run, but have a Wild card - there are two cards I can pull that will allow me to go out and my opponent(s) probably don't know that. If I complete the phase, I have to choose where to put the Wild card and no longer have two options, my opponents know what I need AND I become a target for skip cards. It will then take longer for me to go out and finish the round, giving the others more time to complete their phase.

Comment: @Aaganrmu Ah ok, thanks. While that does generally make sense, I'd still think it would be too big a risk most of the time, considering the main object of the game is to simply complete phases. But if my opponent were on phase 10 and I wasn't yet, then I would do that, because the most important thing is now to stop my opponent from making his phase. But pretty much any other time I'd prioritize just making my phase.